# sistema login laravel com níveis de permissão

Tags: php, laravel, login

Eu estou tentando montar um sistema de login, mas eu não consigo obter o resultado que eu preciso.

Existem três tipos de usuários:

- Admin
- User (alunos)
- Teachers (professores)

Eu adaptei o `make:auth` com *roles* para criar professor e aluno, está funcionando. Porém o *admin* vai registrar os dois usuários, então só ele pode ter acesso à algumas páginas.

Quero saber como posso diferenciar o acesso às páginas, como por exemplo, a página de registro ser acessada somente pelo *admin*. Vi algo de *Laravel gates permissions* etc. Mas não entendi muito bem.

Até cheguei a criar um campo na tabela users *is_admin*, porém não sei o que fazer e como checar nas páginas.

```
public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('name');
            $table->string('email')->unique();
            $table->string('password');
            $table->string('is_admin');
            $table->rememberToken();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('user', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('name');
        $table->string('email')->unique();
        $table->string('password');
        $table->boolean('is_admin')->default(0);
        $table->rememberToken();
        $table->timestamps();
    });
```

Agora só checar na página

```
@if($user->is_admin)
 //código html etc
@endif
```

O melhor seria criar uma Tabela de Regras

```
//Tabela Regra
Schema::create('role', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->increments('id');
    $table->string('name');
});

//Tabela Regra_usuario 
Schema::create('user_role', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->bigInteger('user_id')->unsigned();
    $table->integer('role_id')->unsigned();
    $table->foreign('user_id')
        ->references('id')->on('user');
    $table->foreign('role_id')
        ->references('id')->on('role');
});
```

Agora no *User_Model*

```
public function isAdministrator() {
   return $this->roles()->where('name', 'Administrator')->exists();
}

//na View
@if(Auth::user()->isAdministrator())
    // html etc
@endif
```

Answer (score 0):

Pelo que percebi, você esta usando a coluna is_admin que foi fornecida no exemplo da documentação da Laravel mas nesse caso a mesma não seria a mais adequada pois seus níveis de permissão são 3 e não 2(algo que o is_admin conseguiria comportar facilmente).

Sugiro você mudar a coluna pra inteiro e verificar a permissão com base no nível:

```
$table->integer('permissao')->default(0);
```

E a verificação para :

```
@if($user->permissao == valordepermissao)
  //LIBERE ALGUMA PAGINA
@endif
```